# Deserializer for java.util.List of avro objects

Tags: java, apache-kafka, deserialization, avro, spring-kafka

I need to implement `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer`  to deserialize a List of Avro objects.

The deserialize method of above interface takes in `deserialize(String topic, byte[] data)`  parameters.

I am able to deserialize single avro object (eg: MyCustomJavaDTO) , but unable to deserialize the List of avros(eg: List< MyCustomJavaDTO>); which throws exception : "unable to deserialise"

Comment: So, what is your actual question?

Comment: I want to deserialize the List of avros (eg: List< MyCustomJavaDTO>), 
also edited in the question.